# how to call ajax after 10 sec and my page is load on every sec

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to call my ajax function after 10 sec and my page is load on every sec.

can i store ajax function refresh rate so that after this my function load ?

any solution ? please help me.

below are my code which i am using.

my ajax function

```
function realtime_content()
{

var xmlhttp=false;
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
    {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
if (xmlhttp) 
    {
    RTupdate_query = "RTajax=1&DB=" + DB + "" + groupQS + usergroupQS + "&adastats=" + adastats + "&SIPmonitorLINK=" + SIPmonitorLINK + "&IAXmonitorLINK=" + IAXmonitorLINK + "&usergroup=" + usergroup + "";

    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'demophp'); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlhttp.send(RTupdate_query); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
            document.getElementById("realtime_content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    delete xmlhttp;
    }
}
```

This is my page load function

```
function refresh_display()
{
if ($start_count < 1)
    {
    realtime_content();
    }
$start_count++;
if (ar_seconds > 0)
    {
    document.getElementById("refresh_countdown").innerHTML = "" + ar_seconds + "";
    ar_seconds = (ar_seconds - 1);
    setTimeout("refresh_display()",1000);
    }
else
    {
    document.getElementById("refresh_countdown").innerHTML = "0"
    realtime_content();
    setTimeout("refresh_display()",1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can user localstorage to store the page refresh count and on every 10th count fire the ajax and reset the count

Comment: Can you explain **my page is load on every sec** ?

Answer (score 1):

IN ajax

```
setInterval(function(){yourfunction();}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use timeout, something like this

```
success: function (result) {                               
                        returned_value=result;
           },
           timeout: 10000,
           async: false
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the code : -

```
function refresh_display()
{
  var count = localStorage.getItem("count");
      count = count+1;

  if(count=<10){
  count = 0;
  }

  localStorage.setItem("count", count);

if ($start_count < 1)
    {
    realtime_content();
    }
$start_count++;
if (ar_seconds > 0)
    {
    document.getElementById("refresh_countdown").innerHTML = "" + ar_seconds + "";
    ar_seconds = (ar_seconds - 1);
    setTimeout("refresh_display()",1000);
    }
else
    {
    document.getElementById("refresh_countdown").innerHTML = "0"
    realtime_content();
    setTimeout("refresh_display()",1000);
    }
}
```

and in your other function :-

```
function realtime_content()
{
var count = localStorage.getItem("count");

if(count<10){
return false;
}

var xmlhttp=false;
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
    {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
if (xmlhttp) 
    {
    RTupdate_query = "RTajax=1&DB=" + DB + "" + groupQS + usergroupQS + "&adastats=" + adastats + "&SIPmonitorLINK=" + SIPmonitorLINK + "&IAXmonitorLINK=" + IAXmonitorLINK + "&usergroup=" + usergroup + "";

    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'demophp'); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlhttp.send(RTupdate_query); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
            document.getElementById("realtime_content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    delete xmlhttp;
    }
}
```